# How do I change the font of text in fa-border?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome

I have a mock-up site template made entirely using only HTML5 and CSS3 located [here](https://atoolset.github.io).

I then started with Font Awesome 5, using the CSS webfont option (as appose to the SVG with JS version).

I found a neat trick using `<span class="fas fa-hashtag fa-border" aria-hidden> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</span>` instead of using `<span>` and `<h1>` tags.

Which renders as such, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVG39.jpg).

How do I alter the default font?

P.S. `span {font-family: “Font”, sans-serif;}` does not work.

P.P.S. `.fa-border {font-family: “Font”, sans-serif;}` doesn’t work either.

Comment: `“Font”` shouldn't have curly quotes.

Comment: Didn’t notice, automatic I guess. They’re straight in my code, so I guess it’s okay (notice the copied HTML vs the typed CSS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have used `.fas` class in your span which has font-family `Font Awesome`.

So I will suggest that wrap your icon in an `<i>` tag and then apply font to `<span>`. For border apply `fa-border` class to `<span>`

***Stack Snippet***

```css
span {
  font-family: Verdana;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<span class="fa-border"><i class="fas fa-hashtag"></i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</span>
```

Comment: @MatthewBonnette Apply `fa-border` to the span...Check updated answer...

Answer (score 0):

You added Font-Awesome to the header. But as it only contained one glyph it could not render, so it was replaced with browser default.

Try targeting the :before element instead

```
.fa, .far, .fas {
  font-family: "Roboto"; // or any font you wish to use
}

.fa:before, .far:before, .fas:before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome\ 5 Free";
}
```